# Spring Boot service cannot return payload in AWS - unknown 500 status

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, spring-cloud

I have multiple spring boot services, running in Docker on AWS ECS.  Pretty typical: Spring Cloud Server (Eureka), Config Server, Postgres in RDS.  However, I have one GET call that fails every time.  I have logging that shows me the data pulled from the database, logged, and returned.  No error logs in the CloudWatch, but the curl results in

```
{"timestamp":"2022-12-15T14:10:22.333+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","path”:”/person/aab3f9c6-bcf0-48f9-93f1-9c0b67bb5a39"}
```

And here is the value retrieved from the db:

```
Person person = Person(personId=3, internalId=64ffc6b8-ccd9-4c6c-89d3-411729aa8155, recordIndicator=null, personType=RESIDENT, firstName=Annabeth Jones, lastName=Smith, lastFourSSN=1234, gender=Female, race=null, ethnicity=White, blood=A+, imagePath=null, activationDate=2020-06-07, deactivationDate=null, dateOfBirth=1966-08-26, address=Address(addressId=10, addressLine1=1234 Maple Lane, addressLine2=, city=Colorado Springs, state=CO, zip=77777-1234, latitude=null, longitude=null), subscriptionDate=null, subscriptionId=null, officeInternalId=null)
```

which is then returned this way:

```
 ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(person);
```

There are no errors in the logs, and all other similar calls work correctly.  I am not sure where to look to try and find the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that error means a service can not register with eureka. Seems unrelated. Without the trace of the 500 error, there's not much to try and help with

Comment: Everything registers with Eureka just fine.  This one service just cannot return this payload.  I am at a loss on find where the 500 is coming from so I can track down what is causing it.  I would expect exceptions, but its not happening.

Comment: That does really seem to be strange, is there any exception handler that could swallow the exception?

Comment: Not unless there is something in Spring or AWS I am unaware of.  I have the above code wrapped in try catch block, but I log any exception there...but nothing comes from it.  As far as I can tell the code is working as it should.

Comment: if there is no issue registering with eureka, you should probably change the title

Comment: thank you, I missed that from my original problem post.